# Error al imprimir desde codigo java a una impresora termica techzone TZBE90?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, impresora, ticket

Tengo un problema al mandar imprimir desde un codigo java a una impresora termina techzone TZBE90.

Solo imprime valores y codigos raros, me pueden ayudar?.

Adjunto las imagenes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo java inicia con la clase, donde se envian los parametros que se escribiran en el ticket:
Ticketera.java

```
public class Ticketera {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    String items = "2   Articulo Prueba   15.00\n"
            + "7   Articulo Tara tara   25.00\n"
            + "4   Super articulo   55.39";
    String store = "Picharras Ltd.";
    String venue = "Molas, Yuc.";
    String date = "01/enero/2012";
    String caissier = "Josue Camara";
    TicketUno ticket = new TicketUno(store, venue, "5", "99", caissier, date, items, "100.00", "16.00", "116.00", "150", "34");
    ticket.print();
}
```

}

La clase adicional es TicketUno.java, en esta clase se arma la cadena por medio del constructor donde recibe los parametros para imprimir en el Ticket.

```
public class TicketUno {
private String contentTicket = "VINATERIA {{nameLocal}}\n"
        + "EXPEDIDO EN: {{expedition}}\n"
        + "DOMICILIO CONOCIDO MERIDA, YUC.\n"
        + "=============================\n"
        + "MERIDA, XXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
        + "RFC: XXX-020226-XX9\n"
        + "Caja # {{box}} - Ticket # {{ticket}}\n"
        + "LE ATENDIO: {{cajero}}\n"
        + "{{dateTime}}\n"
        + "=============================\n"
        + "{{items}}\n"
        + "=============================\n"
        + "SUBTOTAL: {{subTotal}}\n"
        + "IVA: {{tax}}\n"
        + "TOTAL: {{total}}\n\n"
        + "RECIBIDO: {{recibo}}\n"
        + "CAMBIO: {{change}}\n\n"
        + "=============================\n"
        + "GRACIAS POR SU COMPRA...\n"
        + "ESPERAMOS SU VISITA NUEVAMENTE {{nameLocal}}\n"
        + "\n"
        + "\n";

TicketUno(String nameLocal, String expedition, String box, String ticket, String caissier, String dateTime, String items, String subTotal, String tax, String total, String recibo, String change) {
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{nameLocal}}", nameLocal);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{expedition}}", expedition);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{box}}", box);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{ticket}}", ticket);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{cajero}}", caissier);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{dateTime}}", dateTime);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{items}}", items);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{subTotal}}", subTotal);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{tax}}", tax);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{total}}", total);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{recibo}}", recibo);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{change}}", change);
}

public void print() {
    PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    byte[] bytes = this.contentTicket.getBytes();

    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;

    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
    DocPrintJob job = null;
    if (services.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
            if (services[i].getName().equals("USB Receipt Printer")) {
                job = services[i].createPrintJob();
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        job.print(doc, null);
    } catch (PrintException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: y cuál es el código?...

Comment: agrege el codigo, seme paso subirlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

!Solucionado!
Solucione mi problema con los siguientes pasos, tomando en cuenta que tengo la Impresora Termica POS TechZone TZBE90 modelo/seria RP58E_U.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1.- Descargar el controlado de la pagina oficial, en mi caso el controlador para MAC.
https://es.rongtatech.com/category/downloads/1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.- Instalar el driver .
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- Configurar la impresora con el driver instalado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4.- Construir el codigo para imprimir:

Clase Ticketera.java

```
public class Ticketera {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    Ticket ticketUno = new Ticket("Alimentos Balanceados Santos", "expedition", "box", "ticket", "caissier",
            "dateTime", "items", "subTotal", "tax", "total", 
            "recibo", "change");
    
    ticketUno.print();
}
```

}

Clase Ticket.java

```
public class Ticket {

private String contentTicket = 
        "=============================\n"
        +"{{nameLocal}}                  \n"
        + "{{expedition}}               \n"
        + "RFC20210623ABS7              \n"
        + "-----------------------------\n"
        + "Ejido Loma de Malacota       \n"
        + "Jiquipilco, Estado de Mexico \n"
        + "8190872290                   \n"
        + "                             \n"
        + "No. Ticket       Fecha       \n"
        + "{{ticket}}    {{dateTime}}   \n"
        + "                             \n"
        + "Cantidad   Precio    Importe \n"
        + "=============================\n"
        + "PERROS CAN PRO MAX LAMINADO CAMPI Bulto de 20 Kilos\n"
        + "2.0      428.00       3368.00 \n"
        + "==============================\n"
        + "                             \n"
        + "                TOTAL: 3368.00\n"
        + "                             \n"
        + "(tres mil trecientos sesenta y ocho)\n"
        + "                             \n"
        + "Efectivo $ 3500\n"
        + "Cambio $ 200\n"
        + "                             \n"
        + "Caja           Cajero        \n"
        + "Caja 3 Oficina Josh Gonzalez \n"
        + "Cliente: Mayoreo\n"
        + "=============================\n"
        + "GRACIAS POR SU COMPRA\n"
        + "El alimento que nutre y da energia a tu ganado.\n"
        + "\n"
        + "\n";

Ticket(String nameLocal, String expedition, String box, String ticket, String caissier, String dateTime, String items, String subTotal, String tax, String total, String recibo, String change) {
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{nameLocal}}", nameLocal);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{expedition}}", expedition);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{box}}", box);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{ticket}}", ticket);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{cajero}}", caissier);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{dateTime}}", dateTime);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{items}}", items);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{subTotal}}", subTotal);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{tax}}", tax);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{total}}", total);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{recibo}}", recibo);
    this.contentTicket = this.contentTicket.replace("{{change}}", change);
}

public void print() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;

    PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService printService[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, pras);
    PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    PrintService service = ServiceUI.printDialog(null, 700, 200, printService, defaultService, flavor, pras);

    byte[] bytes;

    bytes = this.contentTicket.getBytes();
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);

    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

    try {
        job.print(doc, null);
    } catch (Exception er) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al imprimir: " + er.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Mi ticket:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Listo!!!, problema solucionado. Saludos